# Помогите с использованием promise в цикле

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise, coffeescript

У меня есть код

```
ids = [196658162, 244668541, 84634196, 1234567, 45367181]

for id of ids
  id = ids[id]
  url = "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?fields=photo,status&user_ids=#{id}&access_token=#{atom.config.get('vk-messenger.apiToken')}&v=5.60"
  reqWithPromise(url)

reqWithPromise = (url) ->
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) ->
    https.get url, (@response) ->
      @response.on 'data', (chunk) ->
        @userModel = JSON.parse(chunk)['response'][0]
        console.log @userModel.id + ' ' + @userModel.first_name
        resolve()
)
```

в консоле я получаю

```
1234567 Maximka  dialogs-service.coffee:26
244668541 Maxim  dialogs-service.coffee:26
45367181 Daniil  dialogs-service.coffee:26
84634196 Igor    dialogs-service.coffee:26 
196658162 Nikita dialogs-service.coffee:26
```

Помогите, как сделать чтобы запросы отправлялись и приходили последовательно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы знаете ка можно решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы новая операция выполнялась строго после старой - надо начинать делать ее в продолжении старой. Для этого "старое" обещание (promise) нужно сохранять между итерациями цикла:

```
var last = Promise.resolve();
for (var id of ids) {
    let url = `...`;
    last = last.then(() => reqWithPromise(url));
}
```

*(пишу на javascript, потому что с синтаксисом coffeescript не знаком)*

Видно, что переменная last играет роль некоторого аккумулятора, в ней накапливается цепочка вызовов.

Также для построения этой цепочки можно воспользоваться методом `reduce`:

```
ids.reduce((last, id) => last.then(() => reqWithPromise(`...`)), Promise.resolve());
```

Оба способа выше строят длинную цепочку обещаний сразу. Если подобное поведение не устраивает - значит, надо делать цикл через рекурсию:

```
function reqWithPromiseSeq(ids) {
  step(0);

  function step(index) {
      if (index >= ids.length) return;
      var url = `...`;
      reqWithPromise(url).then(() => step(index+1));
  }
}
```

Ну и, наконец, можно отказаться от обещаний и использовать вместо них библиотеку [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) - кажется, функция [`eachSeries`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) делает именно то, что вам нужно.

Comment: первый вариант вертает все 5 раз обьект юзера у которого id последнее у массиве

Comment: @АндрейШостик значит, вы что-то написали не так.